# Why this code not working?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Appreciate if someone could help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

lenlist = 9
while lenlist <= 0:
        print "hello"
        lenlist -= 1
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you ever learned what the operators and words mean? Do you know what's `<=`?

Comment: HINT : YOUR WHILE CONDITION IS WRONG

Comment: yes, It is less than or equal

Comment: it should be `>=0`

Comment: I want to print hello till lenlist become zero, Is that condition is wrong

Comment: Your code meant `while 9 <= 0` (since `lenlist = 9`), so your while condition's never True, therefore it never ran. What you should write is `while lenlist >= 0`, so which your loop will run as long as 9(lenlist) is greater or equal to 0.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
lenlist = 9
while lenlist >= 0:
    print "hello"
    lenlist -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks Prescott, I have check with == as well, it wasnt work,, May be i have learn more about operations

Comment: That would probably be a useful endeavor.  We were all beginners once.

Comment: [Is "Try this." bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661)

Comment: Opps ... edited ....

Comment: But I want to reducing, :q!